# change the color of a ProgressBar based on a variable

Tags: java, android, xml, progress-bar

I'm making an Android app with some ProgressBars. The ProgressBar background must always be white, while the progress color must change based on a variable, for example:

- if i <= 50: the color must be green
- if i > 50: the color must be red

This is the XML file of the ProgressBar style:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="16"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#FFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="16"
            android:useLevel="true">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The progress color is set to white as the background. How could i change it?

Answer (score 0):

Set up your progress bar in xml:

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/nameofyourcustomprogressbar"
```

When you access the spinner you can set the progress color property:

```
ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#bb86fc"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

The  #bb86fc is a color in a hex string format.

If you had listed a color in *values/colors.xml* and wanted to access a color that way:

```
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
</resources>
```

Access the color you want from *values/colors.xml*:

```
Color.parseColor(getString(R.color.purple_200));
```

If you get an error underline - "expected resource of type string" just add the annotation

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved using `spinner.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));`